# Unix Shell - Why are the same $RANDOM numbers repeated?

Tags: bash, unix, random, zsh, kali-linux

I was experimenting with the $RANDOM variable in a Unix shell and noticed something peculiar. I ran the following command, which reads $RANDOM in a loop 100k times and then pipes the output to "uniq" to find the duplicates.

```
$ for i in {1..100000}; do echo $RANDOM; done | uniq -d
```

I ran the command above 7 times, and the same two numbers (4455 and 4117) were repeated all 7 times. The screenshot below shows the command line output.

```
kali@kali:~% for i in {1..100000}; do echo $RANDOM; done | uniq -d
4455
4117
kali@kali:~% for i in {1..100000}; do echo $RANDOM; done | uniq -d
4455
4117
kali@kali:~% for i in {1..100000}; do echo $RANDOM; done | uniq -d
4455
4117
kali@kali:~% for i in {1..100000}; do echo $RANDOM; done | uniq -d
4455
4117
kali@kali:~% for i in {1..100000}; do echo $RANDOM; done | uniq -d
4455
4117
kali@kali:~% for i in {1..100000}; do echo $RANDOM; done | uniq -d
4455
4117
kali@kali:~% for i in {1..100000}; do echo $RANDOM; done | uniq -d
4455
4117
```

See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bpEe.png

I also opened another terminal window and repeated the process. In the second terminal, the numbers were different, but repeated from in a similar fashion. This makes me wonder about when the entropy of the $RANDOM variable, and how it is seeded.

My guess is that it is re-seeded whenever `bash` is invoked, but I was wondering if anyone has any info about why the same values are repeated when I repeat the command in a single terminal window.

Comment: I tried it on my Ubuntu linux subsystem for Windows and I don't get that result. Do you have the same result in another terminal, when you reboot your machine, ...?

Comment: What platform are you using? `The screenshot` Please do not post text in images. Please post the text as text in your question instead. Does the numbers differ in a new shell? Anyway can't reproduce on bash5.0.17 on archlinux5.8.1.

Comment: Have a look at https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html

Comment: @jmg You tagged both zsh and bash. So are you testing the code in bash __or__ zsh? Or do you can repeat the issue on both bash and zsh?

Comment: I also suggest you consider that [Kali is so different from other Linux distributions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux). Being a special-purpose Linux distribution for penetration testing and security auditing, Kali Linux may have special random number generators for this exact reason.

Comment: From `man bash`: `RANDOM: Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer between 0 and 32767 is generated. The sequence of random numbers may be initialized by assigning a value to RANDOM.`

Comment: @Dominique - you may need to increase iterations to 100k or 1million.

Comment: @KamilCuk - Yes, the repeated numbers change in a new shell. I actually mentioned that in the original post.  It seems that the $RANDOM variable is re-seeded when you spawn a new shell instance.  You may also need to increase the number of iterations to 100k or 1million.

Comment: @KamilCuk - I actually performed the test in zsh only.  interestingly, it doesn't happen for me in bash either.  That has me a little curious about what's different between bash and zsh.

Comment: @LéaGris - Yes, Kali is purpose-built, but my understanding is that it is a standard Debian kernel with a collection of packages for pen-testing. So, it should function like any regular Debian-based distro. I'm running it in a VM ,but I don't really think that's relevant here.

Comment: Another piece of anecdotal information: When I run the code in a script (instead of directly in the prompt), the numbers aren't repeated.

Comment: @jmg : Whenever an interactive zsh is spawned, I let it execute (in my startup files) a `RANDOM=$(($(od -vAn -N2 -tu2 < /dev/urandom)))`  to re-seed it from _urandom_. Try whether this helps. Don't know about bash.

Comment: @jmg Two things to mention; Firstly in your posted code there are 100k iterations not 10k and secondly `uniq -d` does not find 'duplicates', it finds duplicated lines that are ADJACENT to each other. To remove all duplicated lines (ignoring their position) `uniq's` input must first be sorted, e.g. `... | sort | uniq -d`.

Comment: @mattst - yeah, I noticed that I missed a zero in the post, but I can't edit for some reason. Thanks for the correction about uniq - you're correct about that. Still very strange behavior though. It appears that it is a bug (a couple of answers down)

Comment: @jmg I've edited your post so that it now says `...which reads $RANDOM in a loop 100k times...` in the 1st paragraph, i.e. 10k changed to 100k. You need 2,000 reputation for *full* editing privileges, i.e. anybody's question or answer, but I don't know why you can't edit your own post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is due to a zsh bug / "behaviour" for RANDOM in subshells. This bug doesn't appear in bash.

```
echo $RANDOM # changes at every run  
echo `echo $RANDOM` # always return the same value until you call the first line
```

Because RANDOM is seeded by its last value, but in a subshell the value obtained is not updated in the main shell.

In `man zshparam`:

```
RANDOM <S>
A  pseudo-random  integer  from 0 to 32767, newly generated each
time this parameter is referenced.  The random number  generator
can be seeded by assigning a numeric value to RANDOM.

The   values   of   RANDOM   form   an  intentionally-repeatable
pseudo-random sequence; subshells  that  reference  RANDOM  will
result  in  identical  pseudo-random  values unless the value of
RANDOM is referenced or seeded in the parent  shell  in  between
subshell invocations.
```

There is even crazier because calling `uniq` creates a subshell

```
for i in {1..10}; do echo $RANDOM; done # changes at every run 
for i in {1..10}; do echo $RANDOM; done | uniq # always the same 10 numbers
```

Source : [Debian bug report 828180](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=828180)

Comment: The $RANDOM variable isn't really intended to be used for anything security-related anyway, so I guess its not a huge deal.

Answer (score 3):

**Pseudo**random number generators are not perfect. The [Lehmer random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator) is used in [bash sources](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/variables.c#L1336) with the "standard" constants:

```
x(n+1) = 16807 * x(n) mod (2**31 - 1)
```

moreover bash limits the [output to 15 bits only](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/variables.c#L1356):

```
#  define BASH_RAND_MAX 32767
...
return ((unsigned int)(rseed & BASH_RAND_MAX));
```

With the seed your shell has been seeded, it just so happens that numbers `4455` and `4117` appear one after another in consecutive output of 10000 random numbers. Nothing surprising there really. You could calculate the seed to get two consecutive numbers knowing that:

```
# We know that lower 15 bits of previous number are equal to 4455
x(n) mod 32768 = 4455
# We know that lower 15 bits of previous number are equal to 4455
x(n+1) mod 32768 = 4455
# We know the relation between next and previous number
x(n+1) = 16807 * x(n) mod (2**31 - 1)
# You could find x(n)
```

> Why are the same $RANDOM numbers repeated?

Because the used pseudorandom generator method in bash sources with the current seed in your shell happens to repeat the same number.

Comment: Yeah, that's in line with what I expected. Thanks for explaining :)

Comment: I performed this test in zsh, but it doesn't happen on the same machine in bash.  Any idea what might be different between zsh and bash?

Comment: kudos for figuring out the seed :)

Comment: `Any idea what might be different between zsh and bash?` Everything, these are different programs.. Most probably the generator in zsh is different - I guessed you are using bash, because you tagged it. Inspect zsh sources and find out what generator is used there.